# Cómo recuperar dos variables en php

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel con php y soy novata.

Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas: 
La tabla Paciente y la tabla Observaciones (1 Paciente * Observaciones)

En el Controlador de Paciente tengo el siguiente método:

```
 public function showPacienteObservacion($id)
    {
        $paciente=Paciente::find($id);
        $observacion=Paciente::find($id)->observaciones()->where('paciente_id',$id)->orderby('created_at','DESC')->take(1)->get();
        return view('Paciente/detalle')->with(['paciente'=>$paciente,'observacion'=>$observacion]);
    }
```

Con el que pretendo conseguir que me devuelva el paciente con su observación más reciente y utilizar ambos en la vista Detalle.

El problema es que en la vista Detalle, abro el formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="{{route('pacientes.showPacienteObservacion',$paciente->id)}}">
```

Y solo me deja trabajar con `$paciente`, cuando utilizo `$observacion` me da error.

Comment: qué error te da?

Comment: Cuando intento usar , por ejemplo, $observacion->peso, me devuelve que no existe tanto peso como observacion.

Comment: ¿qu{e informacion necesitas obtener para la vista?

Comment: Todas las propiedades de las dos variables $paciente y $observacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar la función del controlador esta mal, la correcta es la siguiente:

```
public function showPacienteObservacion($id)
{
    $paciente=Paciente::find($id);
    $observaciones=Paciente::find($id)->observaciones()->where('paciente_id',$id)->get();
    $observacion=$observaciones->sortByDesc('created_at')->first();
    return view('Paciente/detalle')->with(['paciente'=>$paciente,'observacion'=>$observacion]);
}
```

De esta forma, la vista Detalle tiene el paciente con su ULTIMA observación 
En segundo lugar, el form en la vista paciente también estaba mal y el correcto es el siguiente:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get"
                              action="{{route('pacientes.showPacienteObservacion',$paciente->paciente,$observacion->observacion)}}">
```

De esta forma, no da error ninguna de las dos variables ($paciente y $observacion) y se pueden recuperar todas las propiedades de cada una

Comment: Me alegra saber que resolviste el problema, pero estás desaprovechando toda la potencia de Laravel y Eloquent. Éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

Estás un poco confundida con los conceptos de relaciones en Laravel.

Si todo lo que necesitas es las propiedades del paciente y sus observaciones, simplemente puedes cargar la relación por adelantado con Eager Loading, para que la puedas acceder en la vista como una propiedad dinámica:

```
public function showPacienteObservacion($id)
{
    $paciente = Paciente::with('observaciones')->find($id);

    return view('Paciente/detalle')->with(['paciente' => $paciente]);
}
```

De esta forma en la vista podrás obtener las distintas observaciones (casi como un array) como si fuera una simple propiedad de paciente:

```
$paciente->observaciones
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

---

Algo levemente más avanzado pero más al estilo Laravel y que hará más limpio el código aún es utilizar Route Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding