# Obtener el valor de input sin recargar la página y usarlo en otra función

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

Con el siguiente código, obtengo el valor del input IMC para calcular el peso_ideal y que salga automáticamente  sin recargar la página:

```
                    <?php
                        $alt =$paciente->altura;


                        ?>

                        <script>

                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                var imc = 0;
                                var alt= '<?php echo$alt;?>'
                                $("#imc").keyup(function(event) {
                                    imc = $("#imc").val();
                                    $("#peso_ideal").html((imc*Math.pow(alt,2)).toFixed(2)+' Kg');
                                }); </script>
```

Sin embargo, necesito usar el valor que se calcula en  'Peso_ideal' en otra función que deberá salir al mismo tiempo sin recargar la página; 
He probado esto pero no funciona:

```
<?php
                        $alt =$paciente->altura;
                        $af=$observacion->getAfAttribute($paciente->id);
                        $sexo=$paciente->sexo;
                        $edad=$paciente->getEdadAttribute();

                        ?>

                        <script>

                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                var imc = 0;
                                var alt= '<?php echo$alt;?>'
                                $("#imc").keyup(function(event) {
                                    imc = $("#imc").val();
                                    $("#peso_ideal").html((imc*Math.pow(alt,2)).toFixed(2)+' Kg');
                                });

                                var af='<?php echo$af;?>'
                                var alt='<?php echo$alt;?>'
                                var edad='<?php echo$edad;?>'
                                var sexo = '<?php echo$sexo;?>'
                                if(sexo=="Hombre"){
                                    $("#get_ideal").html(((66.4730+(13.751*$("#peso_ideal")+(5.0033*alt)-
                                    (6.755*edad)))*(af)).toFixed(2));
                                }else {
                                    $("#get_ideal").html(((655.0955+(9.463*$("#peso_ideal")+(1.8496*alt)-
                                    (4.6756*edad)))*(af)).toFixed(2));
                                }
                            });

                        </script>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿A qué se debe que hayas eliminado la pregunta anterior de Laravel?https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76904/c%C3%B3mo-recuperar-dos-variables-en-php/ Lo digo porque publiqué una respuesta explicando y resolviendo el problema.

Comment: Porque acabé resolviéndolo pero su respuesta no era correcta

Comment: Sería entonces una buena idea compartir la solución con la comunidad, en vez de borrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor lo calculas dentro de keyup y luego intentas acceder a un elemento html que es un texto con 'kg' al final.
Inténtalo así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var imc = 0;
      var alt= '<?php echo$alt;?>';
      var af='<?php echo$af;?>';
      var edad='<?php echo$edad;?>'
      var sexo = '<?php echo$sexo;?>'
      $("#imc").keyup(function(event) {
          imc = $("#imc").val();
          $("#peso_ideal").html((imc*Math.pow(alt,2)).toFixed(2)+' Kg');
          var peso_ideal = imc*Math.pow(alt,2)).toFixed(2);
          if(sexo=="Hombre"){
              $("#get_ideal").html(((66.4730+(13.751*peso_ideal)+(5.0033*alt)- (6.755*edad)))*(af)).toFixed(2));
          }else {
             $("#get_ideal").html(((655.0955+(9.463*peso_ideal+(1.8496*alt)-(4.6756*edad)))*(af)).toFixed(2));
           }

      });
```

});

Comment: FUNCIONA!! Mil gracias :)

Comment: No hay de que Roledi